# How do I know the weight of this shark?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, anatomy, humanoid

In my game, I mean worldbuilding project... there's a thing called gravity, and gravity affects the weight of everything, and weight has to do with the damage one takes and deals to another, it also has to do with running speed and impact when collapsing on the ground from a fall or when running into a wall or someone who didn't move out of the way fast enough.

This is my sharkman, forgive me for the hands, still learning tridimensional design. the tail is 184 centimeters long and the sharkman is 202 centimeters tall, eyes at 175 centimeters of height, with probably 25 or 30 extra centimeters if the sharkman was standing with extended knees.

### **Dimensions**

105 centimeters neck circumference

75 centimeters arm circumference

62 centimeters forearm circumference

147 centimeters leg circumference

100 centimeters foreleg circumference

141 centimeters tail circumference

[image]

Comment: my rough estimates are anywhere between 150kg to 450kg, which means that I have no Idea.

Comment: If you modelled this out (if so, nice work!) then your 3D sculptor program should have a function to determine the volume of your shape. Multiply that by the average density of a creature (985 kg/m3 or 985 grams/liter for a human) and you have a ballpark estimate.

Comment: To add to KeizerHarm's comment, sharks have a higher density than humans (they sink in water versus a human which would float) so the appropriate average density figure for a shark seems to be 1030 kg/m^3 from some casual Googling.

Comment: Voted up, looks neat ! Good legs, too.. but I wonder if its tail is not a bit too heavy to run comfortably.. it has running legs, so it would have to lift that tail while running as a bipedal (?)

Comment: Heroforge? Looks good so far, anyway! I won't dock you for the horribly unanatomical fantasy tail!

Comment: Create an actual sharkman and politely ask him to step onto a scale. 

Comment: How precise of an estimate are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

It looks roughly ape-like in shape despite the sharkier features. It also looks extremely muscular. It's about the height of a typical silver-back gorilla. My first-pass estimate would, therefore, be the weight of a typical silver-back gorilla.

If you want to get more precise, you could try to compare circumferences. Generally speaking, weight scales quadratically with circumference. So, if your guy is 110% the gorilla's width then he will weight about (1.1)^2 times as much. That said, just eyeballing him his proportions look pretty close. Personally I'd just use the upper end of the gorilla spectrum since he's so muscular and has a tail.

Comment: Silverback gorillas go from 300 pounds to 600 pounds. That looks about right.